# In a primitive symmetric association scheme, why does $E_j$ occur in some power of $E_i$ for each $i,j$?

Tags: algebraic-graph-theory, algebras, algebraic-combinatorics, association-schemes

I am having some trouble in the proof of the Absolute Bound Condition for primitive symmetric association Schemes in the book Algebraic Combinatorics I by Bannai and Ito (Chapter 2, Section 4, Theorem 9):

Let $\chi=(X,\lbrace{R_i\rbrace}_{0\leq i \leq d})$ be a primitive symmetric association scheme of class $d$. Let the $\lbrace E_i\rbrace_{0\leq i\leq d}$ be the primitive idempotents of the adjacency algebra of $\chi$. Denote by $E_i^h$ to be the Hadamard product $\circ$ of $E_i$ with itself $h$ times.
**Since $\chi$ is primitive, we have for any $j$ and $i$ an $0\leq h \leq d$ such that $E_j$ occurs in the linear decomposition of $E_i^h$ with respect to the basis $E_0,\ldots,E_d.$**

I do not understand how the emboldened statement is justified. It says in the book that this is because imprimitivity is a equivalent to there being a suitable rearrangement of indices $1,\ldots,d$ and an index $0<t<d$ such that the Hadamard product $E_i \circ E_j$ is a linear combination of $E_0,E_1,\ldots,E_t$ for all $0\leq i,j \leq t.$

To get an idea, I tried to show this by contradiction on the special case when $d=3$ and the assumption that $E_2$ does not occur in the decomposition of $E_1^h$ for $0\leq h \leq 3.$ With this assumption, we get $q_{11}^2=0$ so
\begin{align*}
E_1^2 = &q_{11}^0 E_0 + q_{11}^1 E_1 + q_{11}^3E_3,\\
E_1^3 =&q_{11}^0(q_{01}^0 E_0 +  q_{01}^1 E_1 + q_{01}^2 E_2 + q_{01}^3 E_3) + q_{11}^1(q_{11}^0 E_0 +  q_{11}^1 E_1 + q_{11}^2 E_2 + q_{11}^3 E_3)\\
      &+q_{11}^3(q_{13}^0 E_0 +  q_{13}^1 E_1 + q_{13}^2 E_2 + q_{13}^3 E_3). 
\end{align*}
Since $E_2$ does not occur in $E_1^3$, the latter gives us $q_{11}^0q_{01}^2 + q_{11}^1 q_{11}^2 + q_{11}^3q_{13}^2 = 0.$ Since $q_{01}^2=0=q_{11}^2,$ we obtain $q_{11}^3q_{13}^2=0.$

If $q_{11}^3=0$, then since $q_{11}^2=0$, we have the linear span of $E_0,E_1$ as a subalgebra of the adjacency algebra, violating primitivity. However, I no longer know what to do when $q_{13}^2=0.$ If I could show $q_{33}^2=0$, then the linear span of $E_0,E_1,E_3$ would form a subalgebra of the adjacency algebra and would violate primitivity. However, I don't know how to show $q_{33}^2=0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *Schur polynomial* in the matrix $E$ is a linear combination of Schur powers of $E$.
If $p(t)$ is a polynomial, write $p\circ E$ to denote the corresponding Schur polynomial in $E$.

If $E_i$ is a spectral idempotent of an association scheme and $p\circ E_i$ is invertible, then $p\circ E_i$ is a linear combination of the Schur idempotents with no coefficient in
the linear combination equal to zero.

Now suppose $E$ is a spectral idempotent and there is no polynomial $p$ such that $p\circ E$ is invertible. We aim to show the scheme is primitive. Let $W$ be the subspace of the Bose-Mesner
algebra of the scheme spanned by the Schur powers of $E$. Note that $A_i(p\circ E)$ is a Schur polynomial in $E$ (because $p\circ E$ is a linear combination of spectral idempotents
and so $A(p\circ E)$ must be a linear combination of a subset of these). Therefore $W$ is invariant
under the full Bose-Mesner algebra. In particular $W$ is closed under matrix multiplication.

Since $W$ is Schur-closed, it has a basis of Schur idempotents. Let $B$ denote their sum.
Then $B$ is the adjacency matrix of a graph and, since the powers of $B$ all lie in $W$,
this graph is not connected. Therefore the scheme is imprimitive.

[Obviously the claim that Bannai and Ito are making is not trivial. It is dual to the fact that if $A_i$ is connected then there is a polynomial $p$ in $A_i$ such that $p(A_i)\circ A_j\ne0$
for all $j$.]

Comment: Thank you for the complete and clear answer Dr. Godsil. I have also been reading some of your books and papers on algebraic graph theory and association schemes to prepare for the research stage of my graduate studies. They have been tremendous help. Regards.

Comment: I managed to complete all of the claims in your response within my notes aside from one: that $A_i(p \circ E)$ is in $W$. 

Since the Bose-Mesner algebra is also spanned by the $E_i$, and these spectral idempotents are orthogonal, the claim that $W$ is invariant under the full Bose-Mesner algebra is thus equivalent to showing any $E_j$ that occurs in the linear decomposition of some Hadamard power of $E$ is itself in $W.$ However, I failed to show this, or the weaker but more important fact that $W$ is closed under matrix multiplication.

Comment: My problem lies in the possibility that some $E_j$ occurs in some $p\circ E$ (and hence, some Hadamard power of $E$) but does not itself belong in $W$.

Comment: @F.Tomas: $p\circ E$ îs a linear combination of some set $S$ of spectral idempotents. since $A_iE_j$ is a scalar multiple of $E_j$, it follows that $A(p\circ E_j)$ is a linear combination of elements of $S$.

Comment: Yes, thanks. It is clear to me that if $S$ were the set of all spectral idempotents that occur in some power of $E$, then $A(p \circ E)$ would be in the span of $S$. However, it is unclear to me why each $E_j \in S$ is in $W$; i.e., why $E_j\in S$ is a linear combination of the Hadamard powers of $E$. For example, if $d=5$, and $E_1^2=E_2+E_4$, $E_1^3=E_3+E_4$, $E_1^4=E_2+E_3+2E_4$, $E_1^5=E_1+E_2+E_3+2E_4$ then row reduction tells us that $E_1^h$ with $0\leq h\leq 5$ only spans a 4 dimensional subspace and so misses some $E_j$ with $0\leq j\leq 4.$

Answer (score 0):

The following supplement is mainly due to Dr. Godsil's excellent answer.

We give a direct way of showing that if for some $0\leq i,j\leq d$ we have that $E_j$ does not occur in the decomposition of any $E_i^h$ for any $0\leq h\leq d$, then it follows that $\chi$ is an imprimitive association scheme. To do this, we will show that there exists a reindexing of the indices $1,\ldots,d$ and an index $0<t<d$ such that the Hadamard product $E_i\circ E_j$ is a linear combination of $E_0,E_1,\ldots,E_t$ for all $0\leq i,j\leq t$.

Without loss of generality, we assume that $E_d$ does not occur in the decomposition of any power $0\leq h\leq d$ of $E_1$. Let $S$ be the set of indices $0\leq j \leq d$ such that $E_j$ occurs in the linear decomposition of some power $0\leq h\leq d$ of $E_1$. Observe that $S$ always contains $0$ and $1$ and never contains $d$. Without loss of generality, we may rearrange the indices such that the indices that occur in $S$ are precisely the first $t<d$ indices $0,1,\ldots,t$ where $t=|S|-1$. It remains to show that if $i,j \in S$ and $k\notin S$, then $q_{ij}^k=0.$ We prove this by contradiction.

Suppose that there exist $i,j \in S$ and $k \notin S$ with $q_{ij}^k>0$. Let $a,b$ be nonnegative integers such that $E_1^a=\sum_r \alpha_rE_r$ and $E_1^b=\sum_r \beta_rE_r$ where $\alpha_i,\beta_j>0$; i.e., such that $E_i$ and $E_j$ respectively occur in $E_1^a$ and $E_1^b$. By multiplying these, we see that $E_1^{a}E_1^b$ contains a term of the form $\alpha_i\beta_j E_i\circ E_j.$ By expanding this, we see that the linear decomposition of $E_1^{a}E_1^{b}$ contains $\alpha_i \beta_j q_{ij}^k E_k$ where $\alpha_i\beta_j q_{ij}^k$ is nonzero. Since the Krein parameters are nonnegative, this term will not be cancelled out by considering the other coefficients of $E_k$ when expanding $E_1^{a}E_1^{b}$. In particular, this implies that $E_k$ occurs in the decomposition of $E^{a+b}.$ If $a+b\leq d$, we are done, for we obtain the contradiction that $k\in S$. If $a+b>d$, note that $E_1^0,\ldots,E_1^{d+1}$ are linearly dependent since the algebra is $d+1$ dimensional. Thus, any power of $E_1$ above $d$ is expressible as a linear combination of powers of $E_1$ at most $d$. Hence, $E_1^{a+b}$ is expressible as a linear combination of the $E_1^h$ where $0\leq h\leq d$. Since $E_k$ occurs in $E_1^{a+b}$, it must occur in some $E_1^h$ where $0\leq h\leq d$. Thus, $k \in S$ and we obtain a contradiction as before.